# Can't seem to save local array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

So I'm running into a problem where I can't seem to save the contents of a local array outside of a for loop. This code iterates through notifsTop (which is a dictionary) and saves the values into another array. However, outside of the for loop, the contents of tempnotifsarray are empty, which doesn't make sense to me since I appended them to an array that is outside of the loop block. I have been struggling with this for some time and can't figure out what is going on. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
func createArray() -> [notificationLabel] {

        let newUserInfo = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let uid = newUserInfo?.uid
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
        let practionerRef =  self.ref.child("users").child(uid!)

        var tempnotifsArray: [notificationLabel] = []





        practionerRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            if let notifsTop = value?["Notifications"] as? NSDictionary { //top of the notifications hierarchy

                for (_, myValue) in notifsTop {
                    // Iterate in here
                    //self.notifications.append(myValue)

                    let notification = notificationLabel(label: myValue as! String)
                    tempnotifsArray.append(notification)

                    //if I print here the array is full with the values I want


                }
            }

        })


        print(tempnotifsArray) //comes out as []

        return tempnotifsArray

    }
```

Comment: That's because the print statement outside of the closure gets printed before the print statement inside the closure. The closure is being executed asynchronously (i.e., the compiler won't wait for the closure to execute, to execute next lines in the function). What you need to do is to rewrite your function to rely on the closure rather than a return statement. For example, if you are updating a tableView with that array, instead of returning a tableView, make your function void, and executed a tableView.reloadData() inside your closure.

Comment: Thank you so much, that helps a lot and would make a lot of sense as to the patters I've been seeing